# Chrome Extension mv3 - how to active service worker

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am migrating a v2 extension to v3. Looking for a way to activate background.js, my extension goes blank as the service worker is killed.

I have tried adding some listeners, they work fine and can log messages, but the service worker not active when the listener is fired.